# Image displaying as URL link in PHP for MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get an image that is saved as a URL in a MySQL database to display on a webpage as an image rather than a URL.  With the code below it displays as a URL:

```
<?php 
// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("server","username","password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 

$id=$_GET["id"]; // Collecting data from query string
if(!is_numeric($id)){ // Checking data it is a number or not
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}
$data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `User_ID`=$id");
$row=mysql_fetch_object($data);
echo mysql_error();


echo"<tr><td colspan='2'>$row->Market_Name</td></tr>";
echo"<tr><td colspan='2'>$row->Days</td></tr>";
echo"<tr><td colspan='2'>$row->Time</td></tr>";
echo"<tr><td colspan='2'>$row->Description</td></tr>";
echo"<tr><td>$row->Image</td><td>$row->Google_Maps</td></tr>";  
echo"<tr><td>$row->Website</td><td>$row->Facebook</td></tr>";


?>
```

If I change this piece of code:

```
echo"<tr><td>$row->Image</td>
```

to:

```
echo"<tr><td><img src='Image/".$row['Image']."' width='150' height='80'>
```

I get the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Is there a way using object rather than array to display an image that is saved as a URL in a MySQL database?

Comment: what this print ?? echo"<tr><td>$row->Image</td>

Comment: For `$row['Image']` to work you'd have had to use `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just exporting the URL from your database rather than telling it to display as an image.

I'd have thought this would do the trick

```
echo "<tr><td><img src='".$row->Image."'></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because your variable is of object type and you are trying to access it as an array.

So use this instead to access that value,

```
echo"<tr><td><img src='Image/".$row->Image."' width='150' height='80'>
```